# Get specific object in JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to access data from a JSON file hosted on the web. The JSON is formated as follows:

```
{"markers":[ 
    { 
    "latitude":57.7973333, 
    "longitude":12.0502107, 
    "title":"Angered", 
    "content":"Representing :)" 
    },

    { 
    "latitude":57.6969943, 
    "longitude":11.9865, 
    "title":"Gothenburg", 
    "content":"Swedens second largest city" 
    } 
]
"markersupdate": []
}
```

My goal is to get the data from the objects, such as latitude and longitude. I tried the following code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'URL TO MY JSON',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length !== 0) {
                //Here I tried using data.markers istead of data, but it did not seem to work
                $.each( data, function (marker, data) {
                      //Here I want to be able to access e.g. data.longitude
                });
            }

        },

    });
```

The problem seems to be that it doesn't import the data correctly.

How do I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are iterating over the `markers` property which is the array. So adjust your `if` condition as well as the object you are iterating over:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.markers.length !== 0) {
        $.each(data.markers, function (index, marker) {
            alert(marker.longitude);
        });
    }
}
```

Also notice that the first parameter of the callback passed to the [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function is the index of the element in the array and the second parameter is the element itself. Alternatively you could use `this` to access the current element that is being iterated upon:

```
$.each(data.markers, function () {
    alert(this.longitude);
});
```

Comment: The success function never runs, I tried adding an error function and discovered that jqXHR.status is 0. I assume the problems lies in my URL? I tried using this, http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/json/demo.json

Comment: Yes, it's possible that the problem lies in the URL. If the remote endpoint doesn't support CORS you will not be able to make cross domain AJAX calls to it.